# Configure Amplify to use existing Cognito token

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I'm working on a app that's uploading files to the S3 bucket using Amplify (JS) Storage.
It's already configured and working fine, but I need to secure it using a policy and allow only a set of users (groups) who will be able to upload files.
I'm getting the Token from Coginito using a backend service, and it's passed to fronted, the only thing now I need to figure out is, how to pass that token to Amplify.
I did try the `federatedSignIn` but it requres a domain, and I really don't need anything to pass except the token.

Answer (score 2):

There's a *(now private)* function on Auth that seems to handle this situation, `_handleAuthResponse`.

Pass the returned url that you get after a successful login, that includes the token to the function.

As it is a private function, it needs this workaround to access _handleAuthResponse:

```
urlWithToken = 'https://localhost:4200/login#access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]&id_token=[ID_TOKEN]&state=[STATE]&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600'

(Auth as any)._handleAuthResponse(urlWithToken)
```

I'm not sure how many of the parameters are necessary, as these are the ones included in the login redirect that we're getting back from a federated signin.

In our Application we're then using a Hub listener to obtain the user details:

```
Hub.listen('auth', ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
    console.log('HUB:', event);
    console.log('HUBData:', data);
    if (event == 'signIn' && data != undefined) {
      //data is a user object
    }
  });
```

This is the reference used to piece this together:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4955

Comment: How can I cast it if I'm using JS instead of TS.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import {
    CognitoUserSession,
    CognitoIdToken,
    CognitoRefreshToken,
    CognitoAccessToken,
} from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";

/**
 * Injects an access token, id token, and refresh token into AWS Amplify for idenity and access
 * management. Cognito will store these tokens in memory and they will persist upon requesting
 * additional pages from the same domain.
 *
 * Calling this method should have the same effect as signing in with Auth.signIn(). When an
 * id or access token expires, Cognito will automatically retrieve new ones using the refresh
 * token passed.
 *
 * Note: Token injection is not "officially" supported by Amplify. The only forms of sign-in
 * Amplify supports are username & password or federated sign-in.
 *
 * @param accessToken The access token to be injected. Access tokens grant access to resources.
 * @param idToken The id token to be injected. Id tokens contain claims about identity.
 * @param refreshToken The refresh token to be injected. Refresh tokens can obtain new access
 * and id tokens for a long period of time (usually up to a year).
 */
const injectTokensIntoAmplify = (accessToken: string, idToken: string, refreshToken: string) => {
    const session = new CognitoUserSession({
        IdToken: new CognitoIdToken({
            IdToken: idToken,
        }),
        RefreshToken: new CognitoRefreshToken({
            RefreshToken: refreshToken,
        }),
        AccessToken: new CognitoAccessToken({
            AccessToken: accessToken,
        }),
    });
    Auth.Credentials.set(session, "session");

    // The function createCognitoUser is private in Amplify. So, we need to cast it
    // in order to call it.
    const currentUser = (Auth as any).createCognitoUser(session.getIdToken().decodePayload()["cognito:username"]);
    // This calls cacheTokens() in Cognito SDK. Assigns the tokens to the local identity.
    currentUser.setSignInUserSession(session);
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).